# Angular JS routing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to route my page to another page once the controller is accessed but its not working. I can route the first two pages but the third one is not working. Can someone help me on this.

This is my routing code:

```
$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/category', {
                    //templateUrl : 'js/partials/course-list.html',
                    controller : 'CategoryController'
                }).
                when('/category/:categoryid', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/film-list.html',
                    controller : 'MovieController'
                }).
                when('/actor/:filmid', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/actor-list.html',
                    controller : 'ActorController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo : '/'
                });
        }
```

Currently my ActorController is not working. Once i click on the movies it should show the actor of the films but in my case its not working

This is my partial html file for the movie-list.html

```
<section>
<h3>{{movieCount}}</h3>
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="movie in movies" data-ng-click="selectFilm($event,movie)"  style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
    </tr>
    <strong>{{successMessage}}</strong>
</table>
```

And this is my controller code

```
).controller('ActorController', 
            [
                '$scope', 
                'dataService', 
                '$routeParams',

                function ($scope, dataService, $routeParams){
                    $scope.actors = [ ];
                    $scope.actorCount = 0;

                    var getActors = function (moviecode) {
                        dataService.getActors(moviecode).then(
                            function (response) {
                                $scope.actorCount = response.rowCount + ' actors';
                                $scope.actors = response.data;
                                $scope.showSuccessMessage = true;
                                $scope.successMessage = "Actor Success";
                            },
                            function (err){
                                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                            }
                        );  // end of getStudents().then
                    };

                // only if there has been a courseid passed in do we bother trying to get the students
                if ($routeParams && $routeParams.filmid) {
                    console.log($routeParams.filmid);
                    getActors($routeParams.filmid);
                }

                }
            ]
        )
```

This is the selectFilm() code from the MovieController

```
$scope.selectedFilm = {};
                    $scope.selectFilm = function ($event,movie) {
                        $scope.selectedFilm = movie;
                        $location.path('/actor/' + movie.film_id); 
                    }
```

This is the movie controller code

```
).controller('MovieController', 
            [
                '$scope', 
                'dataService', 
                '$routeParams',
                '$location',

                function ($scope, dataService, $routeParams, $location){
                    $scope.movies = [ ];
                    $scope.movieCount = 0;

                    var getMovies = function (moviecode) {
                        dataService.getMovies(moviecode).then(
                            function (response) {
                                $scope.movieCount = response.rowCount + ' movies';
                                $scope.movies = response.data;
                                $scope.showSuccessMessage = true;
                                $scope.successMessage = "Movies Success";
                            },
                            function (err){
                                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                            }
                        );  // end of getStudents().then
                    };
                    $scope.selectedFilm = {};
                    $scope.selectFilm = function ($event,movie) {
                        $scope.selectedFilm = movie;
                        $location.path('/actor/' + movie.film_id); 
                        // $window.location.href = '/actor/' + movie.film_id
                        console.log(movie.film_id);

                    }

                // only if there has been a courseid passed in do we bother trying to get the students
                if ($routeParams && $routeParams.categoryid) {
                    console.log($routeParams.categoryid);
                    getMovies($routeParams.categoryid);
                }

                }
            ]
        )
```

Comment: What is the `selectFilm()` code?

Comment: Its the function code where it redirects the user to the actor page for the selected film. I have updated my code with the  selectFilm function in it do take a look

Comment: What if you use `$window.location.href = '/actor/' + movie.film_id`  instead?

Comment: actually i want it to be displayed in the same page, because currently once i click on the category list i can display the movie in the same page below category, so i want it to be once i click on the movie name the actor should be displayed below the movie list

Comment: What about creating an actor directive then with a template and having some condition for displaying it under the movie?  I don't think routing is what you want if you want to stay on the same page and keep the rest of the state the same.

Comment: i just checked the console log its showing error message `ReferenceError: $location is not defined` once i clicked on the movie name

Comment: Did you add the dependency in your MovieController?

Comment: yes i have jsut added now i can click on the movie and its routing to the actor page but the actor name is not showing up the url is showing like this `http://localhost/movieapp/#/actor/undefined`

Comment: Yes, you are using `$location` without injecting it. Along with your other set of string variables, next to $routeParams add $location.

Comment: The actor's name isn't told to show up in the URL. You are expecting `filmId`. See your line `when('/actor/:filmid', {`

Comment: What is the value of `movie` in your `selectFilm` function?  Either set a breakpoint or console.log it.

Comment: @GONeale but according to my database sql query once the movie is selected thelist of actors names will be shown, so which means its passes the filmid technically rite

Comment: @dustmouse i tried to console log it.. its showing undefined

Comment: Ok. Just you said the actor name, so I thought you meant you were expecting that in the url.

Comment: You are using `filmid` in some places, `film_id` in others. I think you want `filmid` possibly so it's not undefined?

Comment: i tried changing it to `filmid` its still not working

Comment: Please use **console.log(movie);** in selectedFilm function and check if the value of film_id is reflecting correctly or not.

Comment: @BharatGupta i tried its showing undefined

Comment: Then the problem is with the value of **movie** in your movie controller. You would need to post the entire movie controller code so that we can check.

Comment: ok sure i have updated my question ocne again with the movie controller code

Comment: Did you do **console.log(movie.film_id);** or **console.log(movie);**? Please use **console.log(movie);** and let us know the output.

Comment: @BharatGupta i did **console.log(movie.film_id);**

Comment: when i use `console.log(movie)` I am getting a like this `Object {title: "APOLLO TEEN", name: "Drama", $$hashKey: "012"}`

Comment: So this means that when you are pulling the list of movies using **getMovies** you don't have any film_id in any of the movie objects. Please ensure that you have film_id in each movie of your movies collection

Comment: but in the database i have the film_id column.

Comment: @BharatGupta can i know what should i do to solve this problem

Comment: i have solved the problem thanks alot to everyone

Comment: "it is not working" is not usually a very helpful description of a problem. Describe what you do, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens instead.

Comment: @Phrogz its ok i have already solved it by myself  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself wher first of all the $location variable was not defined in the function and later on the movie object dont have the film_id so I had to readjust my SQL query to make it work. After changing the SQL query i can route my page now.